# Overwrite Mahapps Metro style for me header Tabitem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mahapps.metro

I am working with WPF and MVVM. I installed Mahapps Metro, this nuget package provides all styles for my app.

I made a TabControl, but the FontSize that Mahapps uses for the header in each TabItem is very big for my application.

I need to create a StaticResource that changes the FontSize of the header in a TabItem without removing others properties that Mahapps provides.

Answer (score 15):

Put the following code in your window's resources like:

```
<Window
......
xmlns:mah="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
......
>
<Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MenuLevel2" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroTabItem}" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="mah:ControlsHelper.HeaderFontSize" Value="24"></Setter>
        </Style>
<Window.Resources>
```

Looking at the source code [ https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.TabControl.xaml ,at line 158] you can see that the programmers made a special exception to set this property, because the font is in a Control Template, inside a Content Presenter. It is easier to set ControlsHelper.HeaderFontSize property.

Comment: This worked for me. My resources tag looks like this    <controls:MetroContentControl.Resources >
        <Style  BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroTabItem}" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="controls:ControlsHelper.HeaderFontSize" Value="20"></Setter>
        </Style>
        
    </controls:MetroContentControl.Resources >

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the above answer, put the below code in Window.Resources

```
    <Window
......
xmlns:mah="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
......
>
<Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MenuLevel2" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroTabItem}" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="mah:ControlsHelper.HeaderFontSize" Value="15"></Setter>
        </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

In the TabItem section add the style details.

```
<TabItem Header="Dimension Alias" Style="{DynamicResource MenuLevel2}">
```

This worked for me.

Comment: missed `/` in `</Window.Resources>`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the API changed since 2019. The 'ControlHelper' doesn't seem to exist anymore. For some info on the changes see: [link to MahApps GitHub issue](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/3711)

Here is the code that works for me:

```
<mah:MetroWindow.Resources>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.TabControl}" TargetType="TabControl">
            <Setter Property="mah:HeaderedControlHelper.HeaderFontSize" Value="12" />
            <Setter Property="mah:HeaderedControlHelper.HeaderFontWeight" Value="Bold" />                 
        </Style>
</mah:MetroWindow.Resources>
```